# When I run the truffle v command in my powershell and get these results

Tags: truffle

Truffle v5.2.2 (core: 5.2.2)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v12.19.0
Web3.js v1.2.9
where is that solidity version coming from? I know i install truffle globally sometimes, so does it ship with solidity or what. Also does solidity version automatically mean solidity compiler version?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this solidity version (yes compiler version) comes with truffle as default, and I think you could change it the used compiler version in the config of the truffle project. down in the truffle-config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know i install truffle globally sometimes,

You can.

If you switch between projects a lot it might be better to install locally, per project, and then access with `./node_modules/.bin/truffle`. That can help when you have to climb into the old time-machine to work on something created way back.

> where is that solidity version coming from
> Solidity v0.5.16

Just a default that corresponds to `Truffle v5.2.2 (core: 5.2.2)`

You can change that in `truffle-config.js` in the root folder of your truffle project. Here, it is configured to get 0.7.6 and "optimize" with "200" runs. Not using the docker container option.

```
  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.7.6",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.7.6" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200
        }
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      }
    }
  }
```

> Also does solidity version automatically mean solidity compiler version?

Yes.

Hope it helps.